# "Last signed in" property in DomainUser class (Google Apps script)

Tags: google-apps-script

I wonder why I can't find the "Last signed in" property in the new and very useful Domain services of Google Apps Script.
In the administrator console of Google Apps Education, every user is listed with a "last signed in" column, but no trace of this property in the DomainUser class !
Any ideas ?
Thanx
Thomas DUFOUR
Montreuil
France

Answer (score 0):

Each of the Apps Script libraries supplied by google, map to google apis. The data point you're looking for is not in the same apiece as where the UserManager class comes from. Look in some of the other google apis and you will see the data point you need. You need to use UrlFetch to get it.